# Elementary question about velocity

Tags: kinematics

When we talk about the nonvanishing velocity of an object, are we assuming we are static relative to the object or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is always relative; there is no such thing as an absolute velocity. If you measure an object to have a non-zero velocity that automatically means it is moving with respect to you. Conversely, if you are static relative to the object that automatically means its velocity is zero relative to you.

Comment: As yes, much appreciated.